# Star ratings shows 'SSSSS' instead of star symbol - woocommerce

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

[image]

Screenshot of my product page which showing `SSSSS` in place of stars. I just upgraded my theme and woocommerce with the latest version and started facing this issue. Before that everything was working good.

I have searched for that issue but couldn't get any solution. What can be the issue? I am little bit new to woocommerce

I have checked `css` file and I show `'\53\53'` & `\73\73` symbols Do I need to replace it with `\e021`?

**UPDATE:**

This code is already there in my `woocommerce.scss`

```
    /**
     * Star ratings
     */
    .star-rating {
        float: right;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        height: 1em;
        line-height: 1;
        font-size: 1em;
        width: 5.4em;
        font-family: 'star';

        &::before {
            content: '\73\73\73\73\73';
            color: darken( $secondary, 10% );
            float: left;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }

        span {
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            padding-top: 1.5em;
        }

        span::before {
            content: '\53\53\53\53\53';
            top: 0;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }
    }

    .woocommerce-product-rating {
        @include clearfix();
        line-height: 2;
        display: block;

        .star-rating {
            margin: 0.5em 4px 0 0;
            float: left;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I have checked css file and I show '\53\53' & \73\73 symbols Do I need to replace it with \e021?" Well? Did you try that? What happened?

Comment: I tried it in firebug but it was not working.

Comment: Firebug is not always the same as changing your CSS and loading the page. Have you confirmed the font *is* loading? Either the font isn't loading or your are trying to show characters that don't exist in the font (ie: using the wrong character for the desired icon).

Comment: SCSS files aren't loaded by websites. Try to change the symbols like I suggested early and re-compile your CSS stylesheet.

Comment: @helgatheviking I have updated symbols in CSS stylesheet as you said but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have any information about what theme you do use, I assume you are missing font which has all weird characters called **glyphs**.

Please take a look inside of your **wp-header.php**, **functions.php** for additional information about font(s), plus check if you have needed fonts inside wp-content/themes/your_theme/some_folder_with_fonts.

Additionally please clear your cache. It is likely to have the same CSS filename while content of the css is different and the 'places' (urls) of the fonts are different right now.

To do so, please push CTLR+SHIFT+R on the page you are visiting. Simplest things. Great problems. Been there many times.

**EDIT: Added missing CSS part with font declaration found in original theme**

So this is the code you are missing in your CSS file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: star;
    src: url(/electro/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.eot);
    src: url(/electro/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(/electro/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.woff) format('woff'),url(/electro/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.ttf) format('truetype'),url(/electro/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.svg#star) format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}
```

This comes from original theme.

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: I am using `electro` theme. Before I updated theme to latest version it was working good so do I need to add font?

Comment: I have cleared cache lots of time before posting this question but unfortunately it's not working yet.

Comment: okay, in this case I think I need to ask you for a URL to take a look, otherwise I can't see any way to help. Sorry.

Comment: `@font-face {
  font-family: 'star';
  src: url("../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.eot");
  src: url("../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.woff") format("woff"), url("../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.svg#star") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }` this code is already there in `style.css`

Comment: In this case please check if your paths to the fonts are correct. I've checked the console and got 4 times 404. Seems you don't have these fonts in `../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. I just solved issue by updating theme with latest version which is released recently.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case font-family is missing or replaced for .star-rating class in css. If so, then add`.star-rating{font-family: star}` in your css and must checked its not overridden by others.

Comment: I have updated my question. `.star-rating{font-family: star}` is already there.